# Problems with apt-get update (-11 -System error) and GitHub

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates, github

I am having some problems when running apt-get update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg
Something wicked happened resolving 'br.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
E: Some index files failed to download. 
They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, when I try to push something to GitHub I receive this error:

```
error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' 
while accessing https://github.com/lapl/HardL1.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

When I am at University it works fine. Any help on fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You seem to have DNS issues on the network you are on. DNS is the protocol to resolve names to IP addresses. Try changing them in your system or router configuration. Maybe the ones from your ISP aren't working properly at this moment. You can use Google Public DNS (`8.8.8.8`) to test it quickly if that solves the issue.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks for your help. I did what you said and everything appears to be working fine :)

Comment: The root issue is DNS. Check for useful response (or error codes) when you run: **`dig archive.ubuntu.com`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your network to use another name server (DNS server) as the current one is failing to resolve the hostnames. Typically your home router has configured a DNS server which it uses to relay the DNS queries to. I can recommend using Google Public DNS services (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) to check out.

Preferably, try to change this setting in your router. If this fails, try setting it on a host-basis. I've described this earlier in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249204/88802) (an excerpt below).

> I would recommend configuring your PC properly using Network Manager.
>   I'm assuming you're using DHCP on your network here (most common).
>   Then do this to perform the same as equivalent to the command you were
>   using:
>
> 1. Open *Edit connections*:
>
>    [image]
> 2. Edit the connection profile you're using.
>
>    [image]
> 3. On the *IPv4 Settings* tab:
>
>    - Method: *Automatic (DHCP) addresses only*
>
>      This setting makes it doing a regular DHCP request for IP address configuration of your host, but it will ignore other non-mandatory
>        options like DNS servers suggested.
>    - DNS Servers: `8.8.8.8`
>    - Hit *Save*
>
>    [image]
>
> Done.

Comment: Hi is there a way to to it via command line?