# Facebook and YouTube not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet, google-chrome, youtube, facebook

Can somebody explain why in my Ubuntu 13.04 the facebook site and youtube site can't be opened by Chrome or Firefox. Other sites can be opened except for this two site. I really need a hand here.

result from `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1402 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:18:a1:c1:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.103/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::223:18ff:fea1:c196/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:61:86:9c:18:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

victor@victornolii:~$ ping -c 4 youtube.com
PING youtube.com (120.28.26.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 120.28.26.50: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=905 ms
64 bytes from 120.28.26.50: icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=2155 ms
64 bytes from 120.28.26.50: icmp_req=4 ttl=50 time=1796 ms
```

Comment: What do you mean "it cannot be opened"? Please be more specific. What is the error you get? "Connection refused", "Could not resolve hostname...", "Connection timed out", "SSL error" etc. If websites aren't reachable from any browser, this is more likely to be a networking issue than an issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: the loading circle just keep rotating without doing anything and it doesn't tell anything regarding what error it is..

Comment: Do you have a proxy server configured? Disable that if you don't need it. Do you have IPv6, but is it failing? Provide the output of `ip addr` run in the terminal. Does running of a live CD change the situation? What happens if you leave the browser loading for a few minutes? It should always provide an error - just be patient! What happens if you go to `https` directly? E.g. https://youtube.com/ What does running `curl -I http://www.youtube.com/` in the terminal give you? And how about `ping -c 4 youtube.com`? Please **edit** your question to provide all this new information.

Comment: sorry to bother you @gertvdijk i'm just a newbie to ubuntu.

Comment: I also see `mtu 1402`. Did you configure that yourself? An ethernet connection is usually configured for an MTU of 1500.

Comment: Here's a long shot - what does you `/etc/hosts` file look like?

Comment: @gertvdijk i configure that myself since i tried to see the internet and read someone post about changing it to 1402. should i change it back to 1500?

Comment: /etc/hosts is not your problem. (Great practical jokes there if you have access to a friend's system!)

Comment: @Marc it looks just like the other files. (can't really comprehend, i'm really new about all this)

Comment: The problem is that when you type `google.com` into your browser, your internet settings include a DNS server which looks up `google.com` and returns the IP address for Google, and your broweser shows you Google. Except yours don't. Somehow, your DNS request is returning a bogus value. I don't see how this can happen innocently. I would right-click on my internet connections icon, edit my connection setting to use a reliable DNS server. OpenDNS is good. It's at 208.67.222.222 for the primary and 208.67.220.220 for the secondary. Save and reconnect. See what happens.

Comment: how do you change the dns?

Comment: @victornolii Read my answer: "Try using Google Public DNS on your system instead. Follow the instructions in this answer on how to do that: http://askubuntu.com/a/310752/88802 "

Comment: should i restart my computer after that?

Answer (score 2):

#### You have DNS issues.

From the `ping` command, I see that your system resolves `youtube.com` to `120.28.26.50`. Well, that is *not* Youtube or Google. No, that's an internet sevice provider in the Philippines. **That's scary.** Somebody is trying to be the "man in the middle" here! Be aware.

Try using Google Public DNS on your system instead. Follow the instructions in this answer on how to do that: https://askubuntu.com/a/310752/88802

---

```
$ whois 120.28.26.50
% [whois.apnic.net node-7]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

inetnum:        120.28.0.0 - 120.28.255.255
netname:        GLOBET-PH
descr:          Globe Telecom/Innove Communication
descr:          Internet Service Provider, Makati City
country:        PH
[...]
```

And it has no reverse DNS (all Google servers have that!):

```
$ host 120.28.26.50
Host 50.26.28.120.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

---

In the Netherlands, it looks like this (and you should have similar results - though the IP address will be different of course):

```
$ whois 173.194.65.93 # result of ping youtube.com
[...]
NetRange:       173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
CIDR:           173.194.0.0/16
OriginAS:       AS15169
NetName:        GOOGLE
[...]

OrgName:        Google Inc.
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US

$ host 173.194.65.93
93.65.194.173.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ee-in-f93.1e100.net.
```

Comment: i live here in the philippines. so it is the internet service provider that makes this? youtube channels can be opened until the video, but it won't play facebook is worse. it just open a empty page.

Comment: @victornolii If this in the `whois` info I added is really your internet service provider, then *they* are pretending to be Youtube! I would not trust this connection anymore.

Comment: yes it is.. thats the company.. but it worked before when i was using windows. can't really imagine whats the problem *newbie issues* haha

Comment: so there is no solution then to change the internet service provider?

Comment: @victornolii I've given some things to try. I can't tell from here what would be the solution - I cannot see your screen and I don't have access to your internet connection. :) Have you tried the suggested change of DNS servers? That **could** be your solution here. And also please include **all** the things you've changed on your system in your question. As you've mentioned changing MTU - what more is there you haven't told us yet?

Comment: i only changed my MTU. you tried to hack me? LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try install restricted packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: i installed restricted packages but it still can't open those pages.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a page not being able to load in a browser - this is only for addons like Adobe Flash and fonts.

Answer (score -1):

I've reached the same error. The problem was resolved after i've changed the interface's MTU to 1464. The original value was 1500.

Comment: Do you live in Philippines?