# can't convert my image by imagemagick on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

How to easily resize images?

I want to use that method on ubuntu 14.04 LTS to convert my image

First install imagemagick

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
convert  -resize 50% source.png dest.jpg
```

It will reduce the size by 50%

You can also specify the size:

```
convert  -resize 1024X768  source.png dest.jpg
```

[image]

but got this output:

```
$ convert -resize 40%   DSC_9702 copy.jpg dest.jpg
The program 'convert' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
[sudo] password for educ:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  imagemagick-common libfftw3-double3 libilmbase6 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5
  libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 netpbm
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc autotrace curl enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads hp2xx
  html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer povray radiance texlive-base-bin transfig
  ufraw-batch libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  imagemagick imagemagick-common libfftw3-double3 libilmbase6 liblqr-1-0
  libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6
  netpbm
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,015 kB of archives. After this operation, 15.1 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfftw3-double3 i386 3.3.3-7ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libilmbase6 i386 1.0.1-6ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main liblqr-1-0 i386 0.4.1-2ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickcore5 i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickwand5 i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libopenexr6 i386 1.6.1-7ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickcore5-extra i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main imagemagick i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libnetpbm10 i386 2:10.0-15ubuntu2   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main netpbm i386 2:10.0-15ubuntu2   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick-common_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_all.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com' 
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-double3_3.3.3-7ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/ilmbase/libilmbase6_1.0.1-6ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libl/liblqr/liblqr-1-0_0.4.1-2ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand5_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr6_1.6.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5-extra_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netpbm-free/libnetpbm10_10.0-15ubuntu2_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netpbm-free/netpbm_10.0-15ubuntu2_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  imagemagick-common libfftw3-double3 libilmbase6 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5
  libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 netpbm
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc autotrace curl enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads hp2xx
  html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer povray radiance texlive-base-bin transfig
  ufraw-batch libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  imagemagick imagemagick-common libfftw3-double3 libilmbase6 liblqr-1-0
  libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6
  netpbm
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,015 kB of archives. After this operation, 15.1 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfftw3-double3 i386 3.3.3-7ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libilmbase6 i386 1.0.1-6ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main liblqr-1-0 i386 0.4.1-2ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickcore5 i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickwand5 i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libopenexr6 i386 1.6.1-7ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmagickcore5-extra i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main imagemagick i386 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libnetpbm10 i386 2:10.0-15ubuntu2   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main netpbm i386 2:10.0-15ubuntu2   Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick-common_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_all.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-double3_3.3.3-7ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/ilmbase/libilmbase6_1.0.1-6ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libl/liblqr/liblqr-1-0_0.4.1-2ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand5_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr6_1.6.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5-extra_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netpbm-free/libnetpbm10_10.0-15ubuntu2_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netpbm-free/netpbm_10.0-15ubuntu2_i386.deb Could not resolve 'ma.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

$ convert -resize 40%   DSC_9702 copy.jpg dest.jpg
The program 'convert' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update` in your terminal?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin Still the same problem

Comment: good, can you `ping ma.archive.ubuntu.com` and `ping 91.189.91.15`?

Comment: yes 64 bytes from cherufe.canonical.com(91.189.88.153):icmp_seq=1365 ttl=47 time=811 ms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get update cannot find ubuntu servers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29071/apt-get-update-cannot-find-ubuntu-servers)

Answer (score 2):

I think there seems to be something wrong with your network configuration, however, you could still ping the archive server with its hostname, which make me a little bit confused...

Anyway, I would suggest you to add alternative DNS servers (provided by Google) by:

```
sudo sh -c "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base"
sudo sh -c "echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base"
```

And make your changes to take effect with:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

After that, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install imagemagick` to install the imagemagick package. And you will be able to use the `convert` command.

Detailed explanation and instruction for configuring this with NetworkManager could be found in this article: [What does "sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249203/what-does-sudo-echo-nameserver-8-8-8-8-etc-resolv-conf-do)

Reference:

1. [Persist dns nameserver for ubuntu 14.04](https://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3630#.VEFU5PldX-t)
2. [How do I set my DNS on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04)