# 18.04 - DNS is not working using Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless, dns

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 since almost 1 month and I'm experiencing following problems since always.

All my packages are updated, currently on `4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

### Airplane mode on start

The first "problem" is that every time the PC starts, the "Airplane mode" is active and therefore Wi-Fi is switched off. Then I have to switch it on manually to let it connect. I also noticed in `Settings->Power` that I must keep Wi-Fi setting to ON because as soon as I set it to OFF, airplane mode is activated. But actually its description says *Turn off Wi-Fi to save power* and since I don't want to turn Wi-Fi off to save power, I thought I had to switch it OFF, but then I can't use Wi-Fi at all.

[image: Settings->Power->Wi-Fi]

---

### DNS is not working using Wi-Fi

While the first problem is not so serious, this one is really annoying. Basically DNS doesn't work at all when I'm connected through Wi-Fi and therefore I can't resolve any hostname. No problems using ethernet connection. So I tried to configure DNS manually on Wi-Fi connection settings, but still it's unable to resolve any hostname. The only thing that works is adding new `nameserver` directives to `/etc/resolv.conf`. However they are removed each time the computer is restarted.

[image: Wi-Fi connection settings]

---

I know that version 18.04 is still beta, but it should be released tomorrow 26.04.2018 as stated on [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule) and for me it doesn't seem really ready.

Does anybody have a solution at least for DNS problem?

Comment: If you think it's not ready then please write bug reports.

Comment: See this bug report for more info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1805025

Answer (score -1):

This is a temporary DNS fix if you have DNS issues

sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf

[What does "sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249203/what-does-sudo-echo-nameserver-8-8-8-8-etc-resolv-conf-do)

Comment: It's pretty clear that you did not actually read the answer that you are referring to.